# How to replace the numbers on the bottom of Bar GraphView with strings?

Tags: android, android-graphview

I'm using jjoe64 GraphView library for creating a bar GraphView in my app.

When I'm creating a new DataPoint, it requires 2 values: X int, and a Y int, like this:

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new BarGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
    new DataPoint(0, -1),
    new DataPoint(1, 5),
    new DataPoint(2, 3),
    new DataPoint(3, 2),
    new DataPoint(4, 6)
});
graph.addSeries(series);
```

What can I do to replace the X int on the bottom with Strings?

**EDIT #1**

[image: By bottom I mean this part where said 0, 0.5, 1...]

Comment: Check EDIT #1. The part where there are numbers like 0, 0.5, 1 and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you call "bottom" is "X-axis". To label it use

```
StaticLabelsFormatter staticLabelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graph);
staticLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(new String[] {"old", "middle", "new"});
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(staticLabelsFormatter);
```

Further reading: [Documentation](http://www.android-graphview.org/documentation/label-formatter)

Or if you use GraphView 3.x:

```
graphView.setHorizontalLabels(new String[] {"0.5", "1", "1.5", "2.0"});
```

Comment: staticLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(new String[] {"", "x ekseni", ""});
OR
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalAxisTitle("y ekseni");